# how to get file location from user side in c# console application. I want full path from user side like "C:\Filepath"

Tags: c#, console

I am using this to get file location from user side but user give the full path but I got only File name not a full path.

```
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    namespace ExampleForChecking
    {
       internal class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[])
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Enter file name:");
               string v = Console.ReadLine();
               var applicationPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(v);
               Console.WriteLine(applicationPath);
           }
        }
   }
```

which are change required for my code to get the full path.

Comment: are you sure user is entering the full path? because in message you are requesting for file name

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Yes, because how to we know where files are stored. and after got full path we can performed some operations on that files.

Comment: where I change in my code to get full path and which method I call?

Comment: basically you are asking user to enter full path of file i.e. `string v = Console.ReadLine();` this line of code is doing. You can use directly `v` if you are sure user is entering correct path on console . Why are you doing `var applicationPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(v);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the file path:");
string sourcePath = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To get the full path of the process running, you can use

```cs
var fullPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

Comment: CurrentDirectory is give the current directory path but I want to any directories path.

Answer (score 0):

`GetDirectoryName` ist tricky. It always removed the last section.

```
userInput = "C:\temp\CrossReferencedContent.txt"
Path.GetDirectoryName(userInput):
Result: "C:\temp"

userInput = "C:\temp"
Path.GetDirectoryName(userInput):
Result: "C:\"

userInput = "C:\temp\"
Path.GetDirectoryName(userInput):
Result: "C:\temp"
```

To get the correct output make sure the path ends with a `\` or a filename.

**Update based on your comment:**

You can use `File.Exists(v)` to validate the Path.

Comment: I wand this from user side as a input "C:\temp\CrossReferencedContent.txt"

Comment: if the user only enters the filename without the path you might use `Path.GetFullPath(v)`